# order by table rows without refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a below table  in which would like to re-order(in ascending) table in case any of the counter value becomes zero.

```
 <table>
     <tr id='col_1'>
       <td><div id='counter_1'>3</div></td>
     </tr>
     <tr id='col_2'>
       <td><div id='counter_2'>3</div></td>      
     </tr>
     <tr id='col_3'>
       <td><div id='counter_3'>1</div></td>
     </tr>
     <tr id='col_4'>
       <td><div id='counter_4'>6</div></td>
    </tr>
     <tr id='col_5'>
       <td><div id='counter_5'>0</div></td>
     </tr>
     <tr id='col_6'>
       <td><div id='counter_6'>5</div></td>
     </tr>
     <tr id='col_7'>
       <td><div id='counter_7'>0</div></td>
     </tr>
     <tr id='col_8'>
       <td><div id='counter_8'>9</div></td>
     </tr>
 </table>
```

Please advice. Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: could you please elaborate? would you like to order by the div ID? or the div inner HTML? and more importantly, why do you need to RE-order? is it responding to some user input? if not, why not just initially order how you want?

Comment: i want order by tr ids.

Comment: are the <tr> IDs being generated by some server side code, and from a DB? if so, perform the sort there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var trs = $('table tr').get();
trs.sort(function (tr1, tr2) {
    return $.trim($(tr1).text()).localeCompare($.trim($(tr2).text()))
});

$('table').append(trs)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4K3sf/)

Comment: How can i get comapred only value between div tags "<div id='counter_5'>0</div>"?

Comment: Thanks arun, after using the suggested code. jquery becomes unresponsive and browser get crashed. Can you please advice ?

Answer (score 0):

```
if($('tr div').text()=='0') return '1';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jquery you could use tablesorter:

http://tablesorter.com/docs/

With a couple extra lines of code you can have a very flexible set of options for your tables.